# Выполнять запросы по цепочке

Tags: java, android, retrofit

У меня в приложении запросы выполняются сразу для всего списка, как можно сделать так, что они выполнялись как по цепочке? Сначала выполнился для 1-го элемента, после того как выполнился, начинает выполнятся для второго.

```
private void loadJSON() {
    Call<List<Integer>> call = request.getTopStories();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Integer>> call, Response<List<Integer>> response) {
            topStories = response.body();
            loadDetails();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Integer>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void loadDetails(){
    for (Integer id : topStories) {
        request.getTopStore(id).enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
                models.add(response.body());
                topStoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу вариант с использованием рекурсии:

Добавляете поле к классу, в котором находятся данные методы:

```
private int mLoadPosition;
```

Перед вызовом метода `loadJSON()` инициализируете поле `mLoadPosition`:

```
mLoadPosition = -1;
```

и изменяете метод `loadDetails()`:

```
private void loadDetails() {
    mLoadPosition++;
    if (mLoadPosition == topStories.size()) {
        return;
    }
    int id = topStories.get(mLoadPosition);
    request.getTopStore(id).enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            models.add(response.body());
            topStoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            loadDetails();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Либо можете использовать *синхронные* запросы, но тогда придется вручную реализовывать выполнение запросов в потоке, отличном от UI-потока.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает корректно, только вот хотел уточнить второй шаг, а именно инициализация поля, можно ведь сразу объявить поле как ` private int mLoadPosition = -1;` чтоб лишний раз его не инициализировать в `onCreate`.

Comment: @Morozov, В таком случае, если второй раз запустить `loadJSON()`, то метод `loadDetails()` сработает некорректно.

Comment: та вроде всё гуд, в любом случае, если что уже знаю как править, спасибо)